# error excel vba "method range object _global failed"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

here is my code

```
Sub rangking()
Dim mulai As Integer
Dim akhir As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Application.CutCopyMode = False
mulai = 0
akhir = 60
For i = akhir To mulai Step -1
If Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 90 Then
Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "mumtaz"
ElseIf Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 80 Then Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "jayid jiddan"
ElseIf Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 70 Then Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "jayid"
ElseIf Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 60 Then Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "hasan"
ElseIf Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 50 Then Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "kaaf"
ElseIf Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 45 Then Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "makbul"
Else: Range("data!AO" & i).Value = "rosib"
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

i have error "method 'range' on object '_global' failed "
in line

```
If Range("data!AC" & i).Value > 90 Then
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range("data!AC" & i)
```

is not a range you need to define your sheet seperately
eg:

```
Sheets("data").Range("AC" & i)
```